# Valgrind insists there's still memory on the heap but I'm freeing the only pointer to the heap I have

Tags: c, valgrind, free, calloc

I'm using Valgrind to find any memory leaks in my code, and according to the output there is 17 bytes that are still reachable, 1 alloc and 0 frees:

```
==9413== 
==9413== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9413==     in use at exit: 17 bytes in 1 blocks
==9413==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 17 bytes allocated
==9413== 
==9413== 17 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==9413==    at 0x402C109: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9413==    by 0x80485F6: main (question3.c:21)
==9413== 
==9413== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9413==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9413==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9413==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9413==    still reachable: 17 bytes in 1 blocks
==9413==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9413== 
==9413== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9413== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The thing is there is only one calloc in my code and I'm definitely freeing the pointer:

```
void checkInput(int err) {
  if (!err || err == EOF) {
    printf("\nInvalid input!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}

#define N 17
int main() {
  char bufferStack[N] = { 'a' };
  char * bufferHeap = calloc(N, sizeof(char));
  char junk[N];
  printf("Enter a string no more than 16 chars long\n0123456789012345\n");
  checkInput(scanf("%16[^\n]", bufferStack));
  printf("BufferStack: %s\n", bufferStack);
  checkInput(scanf("%16[\n]", junk));
  checkInput(scanf("%16[^\n]", bufferHeap));
  printf("BufferHeap: %s\n", bufferHeap);
  free(bufferHeap);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure where (or rather how) the memory is leaking. If anyone can help me find my bug or solve the problem I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly, If your checkInput function fails, the program exits without doing the free.  Kudos for using valgrind

Comment: Do not `exit` in the functions. Return to the caller on error. let the caller decide what to do.

Comment: Given your posted code, I cannot reproduce your output with linux 3.19.8-100 and valgrind 3.9.0. Mine exits (after I enter two lines of text) saying "in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks". I suggest you put the code in a loop iterating until stdin ends redirecting stdin from an input file of a few hundred lines.

Comment: What was the input when you ran this code under Valgrind? Did you see the `"BufferHeap: %s"` message print when you ran this code under Valgrind?

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `calloc()` `malloc()` and `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "calloc failed" );` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile! it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files. In this case: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter more than 16 characters on the first prompt, the first call to `scanf` will pick up the first 16 characters, leaving any remaining characters in the input buffer.

Then when the second `scanf` executes, it expects a newline character.  The next character is not a newline but a character left over from the first prompt.  This causes nothing to be matched, so `scanf` returns 0.  This causes `checkInput` to print an error message and call `exit`, which immediately exits the program without freeing the memory.  This is where the "still reachable" memory is coming from.

You'll need to restructure your code so that all code paths `free` the allocated memory.